# Setting WPF image programmatically from a resource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've been looking for a better answer to my problem, and even when I solved it (not very elegantly) I would like to know if there's any other way.
I've inherited a project I cannot modify too much, I mean, I can only add some other properties or override methods but not changing the base class or interface.

This project contains a class that inherits a WPF grid to modify certain aspects of the behavior. I have to add a new column (by code) with an image. Every single image is already stored into a Resource assembly and declared through static properties, for example, an icon I need is declared like this:

```
MyIcon.Source="{x:Static images:Common.Size_22.icon}"
```

I need to use this icon for my column and I tried every kind of declaration through a package and it didn't work. Finally I decided to embed this Bitmap sending it through a property:

```
<mygrid:MyGridControl Model="{Binding}" Refresh="{Binding Refresh}" 
CommentsImageSource="{x:Static images:Common.Size_22.icon}" />
```

When I create the image cell I have to also create an image object and set source using a conversion between Bitmap and BitmapImage

```
image.Source = ToBitmapSource((System.Drawing.Bitmap)CommentsImageSource);
```

It works but I'm very disappointed with this resolution, is there any better way to do it? I couldn't reference the source file to avoid sending a Bitmap by property.

Comment: It would be nice if you would accept my answer as the correct one. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you have the opportunity to assign the ImageSource in code, I use `BitmapToBitmapSource(Resources.image_name)` with

```
public static BitmapSource BitmapToBitmapSource(Bitmap bitmap)
{
  return Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(bitmap.GetHbitmap(), IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
}
```

This creates an BitmapSource which you then can assign as the ImageSource of your control.

Comment: Great answer, I'm still looking for more information about reducing the solution (not only this part). Thanks for your answer.

Comment: This solution copy the entire Bitmap to RAM and doesn't handle any kind of cache. This means that it'll be allocated each time you load the resource.